# OLE DB or ODBC error. The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed

Tags: sql, sql-server

OLE DB or ODBC error.

An error occurred while processing table 'Query 1'.

The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.

Out of line object 'DataSourceView', referring to ID(s) 'Temp_DSV', has been specified but has not been used.

---

I got the above error when i ran a query in Power Pivot for excel. Can somebody tell me , what might be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

i got this message error too in mylast 7 days.

My solution is running first in example select top 10 * in sql server management studio, then go to excel, running query in power pivot again.

I dont know why this is solve, but it save me, in many times.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your query exceeds the memory limitations of 32bit Excel. Try to limit your query with a WHERE clause.

Also see this related question:

[How to debug OLE DB or ODBC error (import data from MySql to Excel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64027430/how-to-debug-ole-db-or-odbc-error-import-data-from-mysql-to-excel)